Abrasion on the seat stay down to the carbon - any impact on frame stability?
Hello you wise people,
I have a road bike frame that has some abrasion, most likely due to the bike rack. No impact. From the touch I can feel that it goes deeper than just surface level. I believe it got all the way through the paint. Perhaps the carbon layer got scratched as well, I'm not sure if that is carbon already or just black primer. But it has a certain shimmer to it which I believe carbon has.
What do you think? Safe to ride and just paint over? Or structural damage?




It looks like the image hosting provider you are using does not allow hotlinking. Is it ok to rehost them on SE's server? You can click the image icon and paste in the url and it will automatically upload to SE.

Another option is to just link directly to the image. I suggested an edit to do that.

Thank you! It is my first post here

Put some epoxy glue over it, then paint. It is unlikely to cause any problems.
If the frame does crack there eventually, it can be repaired by a specialist for a reasonable cost.
There are various articles about the strength of carbon and reliability.
Use heli tape to protect against rub in other areas to prevent this from happening again.

As I discussed here, where there's a clearer example of abrasion damage, your frame is made up of a number of layers of carbon fiber. I don't know how many is typical. Whatever the typical case, each of those concentric circles you see is one layer that's been abraded through. Your frame depends on all the layers being there.
I would advise getting this repaired rather than riding it. I have a feeling it's acceptable to ride it for a bit, but I wouldn't go do a long ride on it. If it were a seatstay, I have a hunch it's less dangerous, as those don't bear much load.
You can put clear frame protection tape on spots where something is rubbing or may be rubbing. Helicopter tape made by 3M is one example. That said, it's also good to make sure that nothing is rubbing against the frame. I'm not certain how the rack was mounted, but maybe check that first.
I have a feeling that putting epoxy over the abrasion won't have any structural effects.

Thank you for your opinion and the link to the detailed post! The abrasion is indeed on the seatstay, the left one. I think that the paint is quite thick and most of the "depth" comes from it. There are 2 black layers visible, one shiny deep black layer which I believe is the something like a primer, and a matte black, kind of shiny layer which is a little scratched in the middle. So perhaps only the outermost carbon layer is scratched? With these new details, perhaps watchful waiting is acceptable?

Yeah, at least one layer is the paint primer. It doesn’t seem too deep, It’s not a particularly dangerous location for damage, there are no sharp corners and the rear triangle is the least likely to fail catastrophically. I’d follow Noise’s recommendation.

If it were a seatstay, I have a hunch it's less dangerous, as those don't bear much load I'm going to disagree with that - I'd think the seatstays take a significant static weight load - the bottom bracket wants to drop under gravity, with the chainstays flexing upwards, only to be stopped by the seatstays.  I suspect dynamic loads would also be signficant.  I also suspect the loads are pretty much all compression.
